# Jquery, If ID contains letter 'X'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new when it comes into coding, my math teacher gave us a chess problem and I wanted to use javascript to generate all possible solutions.

The problem is: Use only 5 queens on a 5x5 chess board and put them so only 3 fields are unattacked

Right now I'm stuck because my JQuery doesn't work.

U can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hjespshw/1/
Or

HTML:

```
<h2>TextBox value : <label id="msg"></label></h2>
<input id="textbox" value="1" />
<button id="Get">Click</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
    <td id="3"></td>
    <td id="4"></td>
    <td id="5"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="6"></td>
    <td id="7"></td>
    <td id="8"></td>
    <td id="9"></td>
    <td id="10"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="11"></td>
    <td id="12"></td>
    <td id="13"></td>
    <td id="14"></td>
    <td id="15"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="16"></td>
    <td id="17"></td>
    <td id="18"></td>
    <td id="19"></td>
    <td id="20"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="21"></td>
    <td id="22"></td>
    <td id="23"></td>
    <td id="24"></td>
    <td id="25"></td>

  </tr>


</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#Get").click(function() {
  var bla = $('#textbox').val();
  bla = '#' + bla;
  $('#msg').html($('#textbox').val());
  $(bla).text("X");

  $( "td:contains('X')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
  if ($( "td:contains('X')" )) {
        // for every td containing x make adjecent ones turn red
    if ($("#1:contains('X')")) {
        $("#2").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#3").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#4").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#5").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#6").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#7").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#11").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#13").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#16").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#19").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#21").css( "background-color", "red" );
      $("#25").css( "background-color", "red" );
    } else if ($("#2:contains('X')")) {
        $("#1").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#2").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#3").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#4").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#5").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#7").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#8").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#12").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#14").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#17").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#20").css( "background-color", "blue" );
      $("#22").css( "background-color", "blue" );
    }

    }
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table tr td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid blue 3px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

When u type in 1 and click the button all works but when u type in 2 it works like u would type 1.

If I delete

```
if ($("#1:contains('X')")) {
    $("#2").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#3").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#4").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#5").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#6").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#7").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#11").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#13").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#16").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#19").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#21").css( "background-color", "red" );
  $("#25").css( "background-color", "red" );
} else
```

Then when u type 2 it works how it should

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you seriously trying to hard-code every single threatened square for every single queen position?

Comment: Anyway. `$("#1:contains('X')")` returns a jQuery object. It might have zero elements in it, but an object is always `true` when used in an `if`.

Comment: Any idea how to make it so I dont have to hardcode every position?

Comment: One word: Loops.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code stops at 1 all the time is because your if is structured as

```
if () {}
else if () {}
```

After the first `if` is hit (which will always be true), the `else if` cannot be hit as well. You need to use a different value for your `if` statements such as `$('#textbox').val()`

For example:

```
if ($('#textbox').val() == 1) { /* one positions */ }
else if ($('#textbox').val() == 2) { /* two positions */ }
```

Here's my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpv1oyaL/